# Is there any way to hide the iCloud Drive shared files information which follows the file name?

Tags: mac, icloud, finder

I share a bunch of iCloud files for work and the "Added by Me" text takes up a bunch of the file name space, especially when the file name is truncated. Is there any way to hide this?

[image: iCloud Drive "Added by Me]

Comment: My partner prefers Dropbox only because this visual clutter makes column view useless. :-(

Comment: In column view, the column dividers can be dragged left or right for resizing.  Also, if you hover over the name, you see the whole name in a pop-up.  But I agree that I would find that useless comment irritating.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe there is a way to remove this information.